# Upload file takes long in the first time, ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, httppostedfilebase

I recently having a problem in my web application, which is the upload process of my documents.It takes a long time for even a few kb doc/xls to upload.

The way i upload the document is:

```
<input type='file' id='document_file@(letter_process.id)' 
name='document_file@(letter_process.id)' value='Choose File'>
```

Just ignore the razor syntax, i am using input type file to upload doc from a local PC through HttpPost.

AND

This is my httpruntime in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" 
             requestValidationMode="2.0"
             maxRequestLength="4096"
             requestLengthDiskThreshold="256"
             />
```

However,no matter how i tuned the maxRequestLength or requestLengthDiskThreshold, seems not much of a big difference.

After all processing,i will assign it to a variable called file to make use of it.

```
Dim file = Request.Files("document_file" & generate_step)
```

or just other controller making use of other uploads in the same way.

```
Dim documentFile As HttpPostedFileBase = Request.Files("document_file17")
```

That's all of my steps and it functions normally, except it takes quite a long time to upload the file.

Comment: maxrequestlength does not improve the time it takes to upload the file it only restricts the amount of data that can be uploaded

Comment: So indeed, the problem of the long uploading time is more a bandwidth problem? I am still looking for solution about it.

Comment: i think its a bandwidth problem

Comment: yes indeed, when i deployed to an network rather than running it using VS as a localhost, the speed problem solved

Comment: then post that as answer and mark it as answer and close the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, and deployed to different machines, it is bandwidth limitation.